# Need help debugging a LISP script error / octet sequence 141

Tags: excel, lisp

I'm running an Excel macro that calls a LISP script, which has always worked fine in the past, but now it's coming up with this error:

> decoding error on stream 
> # >SB-SYS:FD STREAM for "file:Y\...\FILE0617.CMT"
>    {27B22531}> 
>   (:EXTERNAL-FORMAT :CP1252): 
>    the octet sequence (141) cannot be decoded

What specifically should I be looking for that might be causing this error?  The input file is formatted the same as the ones that worked in the past without error.

What does octet sequence 141 refer to?

Comment: Octet sequence is a character. You probably have mismatching encodings. Your Lisp script tries to read the text as CP1252, but it might be in UTF-9 or something else...

Comment: So do I need to change the encoding of my input file, or search for a specific character that might be causing the problem?

Comment: You can either change the encoding of input file (like with `iconv`) or change the expected encoding in the script

Comment: I think I figured this out.  I wrote a python script to remove all instances of chr(141) in the input file, and the Lisp is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

141 is a cedilla (ç). I'm guessing that you got someone with a name with a ç in it for the first time and Lisp doesn't handle the encoding right.